# Question about Avenson mic

Tags: microphone

Does anybody here have some experience with Avenson sto 2 mics?
I'm pretty curious about them, but I don't know anybody who has used one.

Here is the link: http://www.avensonaudio.com/sto2.php

I wonder if they could have some uses for recording in the field.
What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I have used them quite a bit, since I manufacture these microphones.

Omnidirectional microphones have a few characteristics that make them useful in field recording:

- low handling noise
- better wind rejection than direction microphones
- baffled omnis (ie jecklin disk) can give you stereo effects similar to binaural techniques

If you have any specific questions about the STO-2s feel free to contact me.

Comment: @Brad Avenson Thanks a lot for your reply! i ve heard some examples of music recording with this mics, but i was concerned about noise. I m thinking about give them a try recording effects, but what would be your recommendation about using them in the field? what would you record with them? thanks a lot!

Comment: Brad Avenson + Avenson Mic = Any relation?

Comment: @Brad. What wind jamming possibilities are available for a mic that looks like this?